# How to: two divs floating left one static and the other responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

In my main container which is `.Picture-Black`I have two divs that are floating to the left. `.Picture-Left` And `.Picture-Right` I want the right div to be static while the left one which contain the image is responsive.

I have set `.Picture-Black{max-width: 900px}`

And `.Picture-Left{max-width: 640px}`

And `.Picture-Right{width: 260px}`

What I want to accomplish is to make the image smaller while resizing to the window to less than 900px. Just the left div and the image. I want the right div to stay the same (Static)

What I am facing is that instead of the image being smaller when resizing, it doesn't change and the right div will go to the bottom of the left div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Picture-Black">
<div class="Picture-Left">

    <div class="Picture"><img src="1.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
<div class="Picture-Right">
    <div class="Picture-Info">Hilarious</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info">Original</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Comments 0</div>
    <div class="Picture-Uploader" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Farris</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Hilarious</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Funny</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Okay</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px){

.Picture-Black{
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: auto;
}

.Picture-Left{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}

.Picture-Right{
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-Caption{
    max-width: 620px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #222;
}

.Picture{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-Info{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.Picture-Uploader{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2E8ECE;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.Picture-Rate{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #CE1126;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

}
```

Comment: Just set the img ```width: 100%;``` it will auto set to the parent's width.

Comment: A 300px wide image stretched to cover a 640px wide container means stretching and distortion. It will be visually unpleasant.

Comment: @ILoveCSS I actually don't mind that. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: But what if the img was smaller than 640px? How can I set it to a maximum 640px while making resize to smaller width when window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it's width to 100%

```
.Picture img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
.Picture{
    max-width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture img{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="Picture-Black">
<div class="Picture-Left">
    <div class="Picture-Caption">I want to eat breakfast today not tomorrow</div>
    <div class="Picture"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/50704/car-race-ferrari-racing-car-pirelli-50704.jpeg" /></div>
</div>
<div class="Picture-Right">
    <div class="Picture-Info">Hilarious</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info">Original</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Comments 0</div>
    <div class="Picture-Uploader" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Farris</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Hilarious</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Funny</div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate">Okay</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it did not solve. I think the problem is that the parent div of the image is floating left. I want the right div to be the same but the left div and its children get smaller when resizing the window

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, a `<video>` element is the best responsive image container HTML5 has to offer. Use the `poster` attribute as you'd use the `src` attribute in an `<img>` element. Review it in Full page mode--resizing is flawless. There's no cutoffs or distortion and it maintains it's aspect ratio consistently.

**SNIPPET**

```css
video {
  max-width: 640px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<video poster='http://i.imgur.com/LcHFQNf.jpg' width='100%'></video>
```

Comment: Wot?! I'm +1 with this but it smells a bit unorthodox, any downside to this approach?

Comment: Smells unorthodox? It stinks unorthodox, but other than it being anti-semantic, I have yet to see a downside. It may have SEO issues perhaps?

Comment: This i got to do some research about. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should **use smaller images and stretch them**.

You should **use image sizes that match the size of the div and shrink them for smaller screens** instead.

Set a `max-width` for the containing `<div>` and then set the image's `max-width` to `100%` of the width of the `<div>`

```css
.mycooldiv {
  border: 10px solid darkred;
  width 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="mycooldiv">This Div is 640px but will resize itself for smaller screens - it has a red border
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x1000">The image above is much bigger than the div but will resize itself to fit inside.
</div>
```

Want to take it **a step further**? Use `srcset`

You can specify different image size - in separate files - to be displayed on different screen sizes. More on that in this article

[Responsive Images: If you’re just changing resolutions, use srcset.](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)

Comment: I have played around with the code. It seems like the problem is that the parent div of the image is floating left. The code works fine when there are no floats. But for some weird reason it won't work when the div is floating left

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem ...

All I had to do is set the width to `width: calc(100% - 260px)`

The calc helped me and now it works.

Here is the full solution ...

**HTML**

```
<div class="Picture-Black">
<div class="Picture-Left">
    <div class="Picture-Caption">Men have it good. We don't need time to look good</div>
    <div class="Picture"><img src="1.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
<div class="Picture-R-Bottom">
    <div class="Picture-R-Div">
        <div class="Picture-R-Uploaer">Farris</div>
        <div class="Picture-R-Rate"></div>
        <div class="Picture-R-Share"></div>
        <div class="Picture-R-Comments"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Picture-R-Div MT5"><img src="ad.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
<div class="Picture-Right">
    <div class="Picture-Info">Hilarious</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Original</div>
    <div class="Picture-Uploader" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Farris</div>
    <div class="Picture-Info" style="margin-bottom: 5px"><span class="FL">Comments</span><span class="FR ColRed2">0</span></div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate"><span class="FL">Hilarious</span><span class="FR">123456</span></div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate"><span class="FL">Funny</span><span class="FR">123456</span></div>
    <div class="Picture-Rate"><span class="FL">Okay</span><span class="FR">123456</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){

.Picture-Black{
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #111;
    margin: auto;
}

.Picture-Left{
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}

.Picture-R-Bottom{
    display: none;
}

.Picture-Right{
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-Caption{
    max-width: 640px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #222;
    font-family: cartoon;
}

.Picture{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-Info{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: numbers;
}

.Picture-Uploader{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2E8ECE;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: cartoon;
}

.Picture-Rate{
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #CE1126;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: numbers;
}

.Picture-Rate:hover{
    background-color: #AC0F1F;
    cursor: pointer;
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 599px){

.Picture-Black{
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #111;
}

.Picture-Left{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-Caption{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #222;
    font-family: cartoon;
}

.Picture{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Picture-R-Bottom{
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px;
}

.Picture-Right{
    display: none;
}

.Picture-R-Uploaer{
    width: calc(100% - 185px);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2E8ECE;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: cartoon;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.Picture-R-Rate{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #CE1126;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.Picture-R-Share{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.Picture-R-Comments{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
}

.Picture-R-Div{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
}

}
```